# Is having a lot of render methods within a components bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I had written a component and there are some other instances of small components within that components. Is it a bad practice to use a renderxxx for each instance? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are using some kind of logic for rendering your components, then you should go with dedicated renderX methods. But if all you are doing is to return the components, you should simply describe it with JSX.

Without logic

```
const MyComponent = ({ options }) => (
  <div>
    <SelectList options={options} />
  </div>
);
```

With logic

```
const MyComponent = ({ options }) => {
  const renderOptions = () => {
    if (options.length < 5) {
      return <RadioButtonGroup options={options} />;
    }

    return <SelectList options={options} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderOptions()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Another approch would be wrapping another component around every renderX method.

```
const OptionsRenderer = ({ options }) => {
  if (options.length < 5) {
    return <RadioButtonGroup options={options} />;
  }

  return <SelectList options={options} />;
};

const MyComponent = ({ options }) => (
  <div>
    <OptionsRenderer options={options} />
  </div>
);
```